# Nodejs and Ionic i stuck on begin created apps

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I create apps using ionic,
I stuck in here:

```
E:\Work\MyProject>ionic start myapp tabs

√ Creating directory .\myapp - done!
√ Downloading and extracting tabs starter - done!

? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes
√ Personalizing ionic.config.json and package.json - done!
> ionic integrations enable cordova --quiet
√ Downloading integration cordova - done!
√ Copying integrations files to project - done!
[OK] Added cordova integration!

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

  *   IONIC  DEVAPP  *

 Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app

  -     Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
  -     LiveReload for instant style and JS updates

 ️-->    Install DevApp: ....   <--

> npm i
/ Running command
```

Can someone help me?
I have done all need to create ionic.

Answer (score 0):

the same problem with you, after the long time "running command", you will get a heap out of memory error.

This problem appears when you run `ionic start myappName templateName` to create an ionic project

Answer (score 0):

You need to only create an ionic project then follow instructions:
install ionic.

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

2. Check ionic dependencies.
3. If all set, run:

`ionic start myapp tabs`

4. Now run

`ionic serve -p 8080`

5. Build for platform

`ionic cordova prepare`

`ionic cordova build <platform>`

6. Enjoy.